# Clicking Hamburger Icon does not open Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I have simple a navigation drawer app and the navigation drawer and hamburger is work fine in my main activity.

In the "Visiting Place" activity I do all things the same as the Main activity. All I am trying to do is to open a NavigationDrawer by pressing the "hamburger" icon in the top left corner. The "hamburger" button is visible, and when I start to pull from the left I see the animation on the button but pressing the button does not open/close the NavigationDrawer as I expect in My "Visiting Place activity".

Sorry for any confusion, below is the simplified code I am currently attempting to use:

This is my main activity code:

```
    package com.example.android.raidighitour;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout =(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        Intent i1= new Intent(this,VisitingPlace.class);


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id= item.getItemId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.home:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"THis is home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.visiting_place:
                        startActivity(i1);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });


        ImageView visiting_place=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_visiting_place);

        visiting_place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,VisitingPlace.class);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))return  true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my Acitivity_Main.XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/sliding_image"
            android:flipInterval="3000">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/jatardeul"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/raj_hotel"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/raidighi_college"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/raidighi_high_school"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/raidighi_rural_hospital"/>

        </ViewFlipper>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/sliding_image"
            android:id="@+id/first_row_circular_images"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circular"
                android:src= "@drawable/visiting_place"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/image_visiting_place"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circular"
                android:src= "@drawable/emergency_help"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circular"
                android:src= "@drawable/public_place"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/first_row_circular_images"
            android:id="@+id/second_row_circular_images"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"

                android:background="@drawable/circular"
                android:src= "@drawable/exiting_point"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circular"
                android:src= "@drawable/events"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circular"
                android:src= "@drawable/education"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/second_row_circular_images"
            android:text="Hi this is a editable text. U can edit it."
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:textSize="49sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="60dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Visiting Place Code:

```
package com.example.android.raidighitour;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class VisitingPlace extends AppCompatActivity {


    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visiting_place);


        drawerLayout =(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.visiting_place);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        Intent home_acitivity= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id= item.getItemId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.home:
                        startActivity(home_acitivity);
                        break;
                    case R.id.visiting_place:
                        break;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Visiting_Place XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/visiting_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    tools:context=".VisitingPlace"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:text="This is visiting place"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `onOptionsItemSelected` in the `VisitingPlace` activity as well.
Are you implementing this?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    case R.id.home:
                        startActivity(home_acitivity);
                        break;
                    case R.id.visiting_place:
                        //Does not do anything!
                        break;
                    default:
                        return true;
```

Maybe accidentally forget write codes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `R.id.home` try to use `android.R.id.home`.